# Cannot Insert duplicate key on related table

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, many-to-many

My model has Owners and Complexes. An owner can have many complexes, and a complex could theoretically have multiple owners (joint ownership). I want to be able to create new complexes and owners independently, so neither should require the other. However, when I try to add a new complex, I get this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Owners'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Owners'. The duplicate key value is (fcd72b09-b1ef-4894-83de-cb4897c0c401).
>   The statement has been terminated.

For the record, there is currently one existing owner (with the ID mentioned in the error). The owner is already associated with another complex. I should be able to add a new complex with this owner, but obviously it's not allowing me to.

What do I need to change with my model to accomodate this? Relevant code follows:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Complex>().ToTable("Complex");
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>().ToTable("Unit");
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Addresses");
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().ToTable("Tenant");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInfo>().ToTable("Contacts");

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Complex>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Owner)
            .WithMany(x => x.Complexes);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Complex)
            .WithMany(x => x.Units);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Complexes);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Owner and Complex models:

```
public class Owner
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? ContactInfoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactInfoId")]
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StaffMember> Employees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Complex> Complexes { get; set; }

    public Owner()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Employees = new HashSet<StaffMember>();
        this.Complexes = new HashSet<Complex>();
    }

    public void AddEmployee(StaffMember employee)
    {
        Employees.Add(employee);
    }

    public void AddComplex(Complex complex)
    {
        Complexes.Add(complex);
    }
}

public class Complex
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? OwnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

    public Guid? AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StaffMember> StaffMembers { get; set; }

    public Complex()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Units = new HashSet<Unit>();
        this.StaffMembers = new HashSet<StaffMember>();
    }

    public void AddUnit(Unit unit)
    {
        Units.Add(unit);
    }

    public void AddStaff(StaffMember staffMember)
    {
        StaffMembers.Add(staffMember);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your entities aren't setup correctly. In your `Complex` object, you are stating that it has only 1 owner so you're setting it up as a one to many instead of a many to many. If you set it as a collection instead of an object, EF will handle the many to many table for you.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense I think. What about the fluent API stuff? Is that at all relevant or am I misunderstanding its use?

Comment: Made these changes and still seeing the duplicate key error.

Comment: Nevermind - I had to attach the "duplicate" entity to the db context so that it wouldn't attempt to recreate it. That fixed the issue.

Comment: I'll make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entities aren't setup correctly. In your `Complex` object, you are stating that it has only 1 owner so you're setting it up as a one to many instead of a many to many. If you set it as a collection instead of an object, EF will handle the many to many table for you